# setTimeout() does not delay

Tags: javascript

I am using the following piece of JavaScript in my [website](http://www.fbstatussearch.com) `setTimeout()` does not delay the function calling by `5` seconds.

```
function myFunction() {
    param = $('#search').val();
    //alert("I am an alert box!");
    if (param != "") {
        $("#status").show();
        //alert("Show ");
        var u = 'https://graph.facebook.com/search/?callback=&limit=5&q='+param;
        $("#data").empty();     
        alert("Wait for 5 sec?");
        setTimeout(getResults(u),50000);    // this line
        //getResults(u);
        //alert("When myFunction runs show more line 20");
        $("#more").show(); 
        }

    $("#more").click(function () { 
    $("#status").show();
    //alert("Show ");
    $("#more").hide();  
    pageTracker._trackPageview('/?q=/more');
    var u = nexturl;
    getResults(u);
  });
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You're calling the function itself instead of passing a function for `setTimeout` to call, try

```
 setTimeout(function(){
    getResults(u);
 },5000);//note time is in miliseconds, so 5 seconds is 5000 not 50000
```

Instead of `setTimeout(getResults(u),50000);`

I've created a [small fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/akqJJ/) to illustrate how this works.

Here is [the MDN article](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/DOM/window.setTimeout) about `setTimeout`. It has nice examples about how it works.